# Reformat a big C# file by order of Class Names, their properties , etc. ( need it to keep the auto generated files remain in the same order)

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I tried format document but that just prettifies the code, is there a tool to reorder the appearance of the namespaces, classes, their properties in a file ( lexicographical or otherwise ) so that two autogenerated files can be textually compared to each other?

Human generated files don't have more than a class in a file, or they are hierarchical when there are many classes in the same file, so no need to resort the order of classes and their properties, but is there a tool to reformat and order a file by Class names, fields, properties, Method names and signatures?

The original problem is with updating WCF service, moves classes all over the Reference.cs file.

**Edit** :
To reproduce just update a WCF service and watch the Reference.cs file being completely juxtaposed, classes move up and down in the file. Trying to have a large autogenerated C# file sorted in unique way to enable textual comparison while the structure remains isomorphic to the original code.

**Edit 2**: Concrete example code
Suppose file is as below  (psudo code)

```
Namespace S2
{
   Class C2
   Method M2
   Property P2
   Constructor CTOR2
   Field F2
   Method M1
   Property P1
   Field F1
   Constructor CTOR1
}

Namespace S1
{
   Class C1
   Method M2
   Property P2
   Constructor CTOR2
   Field F2
   Method M1
   Property P1
   Field F1
   Constructor CTOR1
}
```

then after sorted formatting it would be

```
Namespace S1
{
   Class C1
   Constructor CTOR1
   Constructor CTOR2
   Field F1
   Field F2
   Property P1
   Property P2
   Method M1
   Method M2
}

Namespace S2
{
   Class C2
   Constructor CTOR1
   Constructor CTOR2
   Field F1
   Field F2
   Property P1
   Property P2
   Method M1
   Method M2
}
```

Note : it doesnt matter what the order of properties, methods, fields are apearing, as long as after the sort they always apear in the same order.

Comment: Could you please share a minimal, reproducible example with us and clarify the main issue when you create your vsix project or extension codes? Besides, you could refer to  [this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c43cfbfd-7a27-4972-bf72-84c7c8d37c4c/visual-studio-extension-how-to-sort-usings-by-assembly?forum=vsx).

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT  : To reproduce just update a WCF service and watch the Reference.cs file being completely juxtaposed, classes move up and down in the file. Having a large file sorted in unique way to enable textual comparison while the structure remains isomorphic to the original code. I'll add this to my post

Answer (score 1):

> is there a tool to reorder the appearance of the namespaces, classes,
>   their properties in a file ( lexicographical or otherwise ) so that
>   two autogenerated files can be textually compared to each other?

After spending a long time serching it, I found these:

**1)** [Resharper extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgdeEp8Xx5wIVA7aWCh3wMAEIEAAYASAAEgKkv_D_BwE) and its Greenkeeper has stated [this](https://bitbucket.org/denniskniep/greenkeeper/wiki/SortingDeclarations).

**2)** [CodeMaid extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid)

**But** l am not sure whether these extensions meet all your requirements and if that still is not what you're looking for, I'm afraid what you want is not supported so far.

I recommend you could post a feature request in our [User Voice forum(DC)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)----`suggest a feature` to share your idea.

**Besides**, you could share the link in this thread and anyone who is interested in this including us will vote it to get the attention of Microsoft as soon as possible.

Hope it could help you.